# Is it possible that background work is skipped?

Tags: swift, multithreading

In Swift a lot of code runs in background threads. But some code has to be done in foreground (main thread).

`DispatchQueue.main` means you want to call the code inside block `{}` on main thread. Eg a tableReload.

```
let tableData = // get freshdata (A)

DispatchQueue.main.async{
  // tableReload with the new tableData (B)
}
```

Is it possible that (in some specific situation) part (B) is executed before part (A)?

Comment: it depends. Is `get freshdata (A)` synchrone or asynchrone? Since it's pseudo code, it's unclear what's really happening.  But if it synchrone, it will process all the code of the line, and later, call the dispatch, serialy, instruction per instruction, line per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your pseudo-code represents sequential lines of actual source code, the answer is "no" in one sense, and "yes" in another sense.  I'll explain what I mean, but first let's replace the comments with some function calls:

```swift
let tableData = getTableData() 

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    reloadTableData(from: tableData)
}
```

The sense in which the answer is "no, A will always be called before B" is that `getTableData()` will 100% for sure be called before `reloadTableData(from:)` for the simple reason that it is called before the `async` call is even set up.  The sequence is

1. `getTableData()` is called
2. `tableData` is assigned the return value from `getTableData()`
3. `DispatchQueue.main.async` *schedules* the closure to be run on the next main thread run loop iteration.
4. At some point, on the main thread, which might be different from the thread for steps 1-3, the main run loop checks if there are any scheduled tasks, and there is at least one, because you put one there, and it will execute them in order they were queued.
5. One of the tasks is your closure, so `reloadTableData(from:)` is called.

The sense in which the answer is "Yes, B can execute before A" stems from being less pedantic about what you mean by executing A.   If you're asking if B can begin executing before all of the work spawned by A is done, then yes.  If `getTableData()`, that is, A, does asynchronous work, and immediately returns some kind of place-holder/future to avoid blocking, then it's entirely possible that B, which is `reloadTableData(from:)` could execute before the asynchronous part of A is done, or even before the asynchronous part of A starts.

However, as long as `getTableData()` returns the actual data you need, and not some kind of place-holder, the problematic scenario can't happen.

Comment: I was asking basically: is it possible that B begins before A is done. So you suggest that that is possible for this implementation when in command A some subthread is activated. Sounds logical now I think about it. Thanks